# After append, there's no jquery effect

Tags: jquery, append

I've a jquery tooltip in my document for wherever with `rel='tooltip'`. Then I try to append a content with it inside like this:

```
$("#justfortesting").append("<a href='#' rel='tooltip' title='Delete 123'>Click to delete</a>");
```

But after above content is appended, there's no tooltip when I mouse over the "Click to delete".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check about live() function in jquery.

Comment: @ManjulaWeerasinge `live()` is deprecated in favor of `on()`.

Comment: How are the tooltips added to the DOM ? Plugin?

Comment: @Manjula: I don't think event delegation will help here (assuming the functionality is bound to the elements by a plugin on page load).

Comment: Juhana is right.You are appending content after initial page load thts why it doesnt

Comment: @Juhana Yes and thanks, I just noticed. I worked in web programming sometime ago. So didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Define the tooltip event like example to taking into account the elements dynamicaly created :

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '[rel="tooltip"]', function(e){
  //Code executed for all mouseover events on ALL elements with attribute rel equal to tooltip
});
```

**EDIT**

Create the tootip after your apend action

```
$("#justfortesting").append("<a id='my-new-link' href='#' rel='tooltip' title='Delete 123'>Click to delete</a>");
//Call the tootip creation method
$('#my-new-link').tooltip(...)
```